# Rewriting File IO from urllib to csvreader

Tags: python, matplotlib, urllib

I am attempting to rewrite the following script, as shown here:
https://github.com/rougier/LinuxMag-HS-2014/blob/master/matplotlib/earthquakes.py

which reads in earthquake latitude, longitude, and magnitude data from an online CSV file. I want to rewrite the data input so that rather than using urllib, and reading it from a URL, I want to use the csv module to read in the earthquake latitude, longitude, and magnitude.  I am slightly confused as to how to perfectly rewrite the File IO part of the original script, so that I can use my own CSV file rather than having to pull it off the internet (as shown in the original).

1. Here's the File IO part of the Original Script (same as in above link):

   ```
   import urllib
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib
   matplotlib.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
   from  matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


   # Open the earthquake data
   # -------------------------
   # -> http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/csv.php
   feed = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/"
   # Earthquakes of magnitude > 4.5 in the past 30 days
   url = urllib.urlopen(feed + "4.5_month.csv")

   # Set earthquake data
   data = url.read().split('\n')[+1:-1]
   E = np.zeros(len(data), dtype=[('position',  float, 2),
                                  ('magnitude', float, 1)])
   for i in range(len(data)):
       row = data[i].split(',')
       E['position'][i] = float(row[2]),float(row[1])
       E['magnitude'][i] = float(row[4])


   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
   ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
   P = np.zeros(50, dtype=[('position', float, 2),
                           ('size',     float, 1),
                           ('growth',   float, 1),
                           ('color',    float, 4)])
   ```
2. Here is the beginning of my rewrite to include my own CSV file (not using urlib)

   ```
   import matplotlib
   from pylab import load
   import numpy as np
   from numpy import loadtxt
   from pylab import save
   matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
   matplotlib.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
   from  matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
   import csv
   eq_data = open('mycsvfile.csv')
   lats, lons = [], []
   magnitudes = []

   with open(eq_data, 'rb') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       reader.next() # To ignore the first row
       for row in reader:
           lats.append(float(row(1)))
           lons.append(float(row(2)))
           magnitudes.append(float(row[6]))
   # After reading in the csv file, this is where I get confused.    

   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
   ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

   # 10 represents the number of simultaneous displayed earthquakes
   P = np.zeros(10, dtype=[('position', float, 2),
                           ('size', float, 1),
                           ('growth', float, 1),
                           ('color',   float, 4)])
   ```

I wish to figure out how to rewrite the section of code from the original, after #set earthquake data, after I read in my own CSV file.  Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Comment: You're going to need to indent the 3 lines following your "for row in reader:" line

Comment: Your code seems fine other than you using `row[6]` instead of `row[4]` , are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi Anand, I'm receiving the following error:
  `File "./antarctica_earthquake_anim.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open(eq_data, 'rb') as f:
   TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found`

It's difficult to describe, but I'm attempting to recreate the link script, without having to use urllib to bring in my data, and I'm getting confused on the float values.  With practice I will prevail.

Answer (score 1):

As you say in the comments -

> I'm receiving the following error:
>
> ```
>  File "./antarctica_earthquake_anim.py", line 19, 
>    in <module> with open(eq_data, 'rb') as f: 
>  TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
> ```

The issue is in lines -

```
eq_data = open('mycsvfile.csv')
...
with open(eq_data, 'rb') as f:
```

You are first openning the file `eq_data` and then passing that in to `open()` again , that does not work.

`open()` needs the filename as the first argument , not a `file` object. Try doing -

```
 with open('mycsvfile.csv') as f:
```

Without openning any `eq_data` before this.

Also, in your `urllib` code, you seem to be using `row[4]` for magnitude, but in your `csv` version you are using `row[6]` , you should use the correct one in your `csv` (whichever is the correct one).

Comment: Hello Anand, I will give this a shot to see if it'll solve my issue.  Thanks for your help!